# i want to see my real IP while connecting with localhost

Tags: geolocation, ip, xampp

i am working with Xampp to create a localhost and i use [geoplugin extension](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php) to get visitors country name. but of course i am working with a localhost my ip address always return to me ::1 or 127.0.0.1 and geoplugin extension returns all variables NULL to me.

i want to make a few example how my geoplugin extension works well or not.Is there any way getting my real IP address

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your website with its public IP (to find this out, [google what is my IP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip)).

Comment: i tried it didn't work but all codes are returning NULL. what could be the problem?

Comment: @user3301042 Is it NULL when you are accessing it from elsewhere? Could you post your code?